# как в двумерный массив засунуть строки с разделителем из файла?

Tags: powershell

В файле значений типа знач;знач. В голову пришло что-то по типу такого

```
 for ($i=0;$i -le $input.Length;$i++){
$arr = $input.split("`n")
    $arr[$i].split(";")
}
```

но результат не правильно отрабатывает

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, подробнее, что вы хотите получить на выходе, и что значит "неправильно отрабатывает"?